# Creating profiles and using count for dicitonary

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is going to be a hard one to explain but I will try my best.

So I have a text file, which is a paragraph. I have recently converted the paragraph to contain only unique words (no stop word). An example shown here:

```
'mississippi worth reading about', ' commonplace river contrary ways remarkable', ' considering missouri main branch longest river world--four miles', ' seems safe crookedest river world part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy-five', ' discharges water st', ' lawrence twenty-five rhine thirty-eight thames', ' river vast drainage-basin draws water supply twenty-eight states territories delaware atlantic seaboard country idaho pacific slope spread forty-five degrees longitude', ' mississippi receives carries gulf water fifty-four subordinate rivers navigable steamboats hundreds navigable flats keels', ' area drainage-basin combined areas england wales scotland ireland france spain portugal germany austria italy turkey almost wide region fertile mississippi valley proper exceptionally so']
```

What I have done here is split the paragraph into sentences and removed any punctuations. I then put it into a list.

so for example the list is called **temp**, If I print out print(temp[0]) it will output this:

```
'mississippi worth reading about'
```

Fantastic. However my next step which I am stuck on is I'm trying to create a mini thesaurus using th cosine similarity equation which maybe a few of you are familiar with.

However, first I want to create some profiles. I'll give one profile example as **'River'**. In the temp list each element is a sentence. What I want to achieve is for every sentence that contains the word river, create a count of every other word in that sentence.

so if I had `'commonplace river contrary ways remarkable'` which is temp[1] the start of the dictionary using the count method would be.

```
{'commonplace': 1, 'river': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'ways': 1, 'remarkable': 1,}
```

the first look at the output will be:

```
river 1 (profile word)
   commonplace: 1
   contrary: 1
   remarkable: 1
   ways: 1
```

So for every sentence that has river in this should be the final output.

```
river 4 (profile)
    atlantic: 1
    branch: 1
    commonplace: 1
    considering: 1
    contrary: 1
    country: 1
    cover: 1
    crookedest: 1
    crow: 1
    degrees: 1
    delaware: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    draws: 1
    fly: 1
    forty-five: 1
    ground: 1
    idaho: 1
    journey: 1
    longest: 1
    longitude: 1
    main: 1
    missouri: 1
    pacific: 1
    part: 1
    remarkable: 1
    safe: 1
    seaboard: 1
    seems: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    six: 1
    slope: 1
    spread: 1
    states: 1
    supply: 1
    territories: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    uses: 1
    vast: 1
    water: 1
    ways: 1
```

I'm not sure if it's better to just have a whole list of unique words instead of unique words split into a sentence as an element. For example, this is a set of the above words from the first list.

```
{'austria', 'fortyfive', 'fiftyfour', 'longest', 'vast', 'almost', 'states', 'region', 'commonplace', 'wide', 'flats', 'main', 'longitude', 'part', 'gulf', 'st', 'contrary', 'missouri', 'pacific', 'hundreds', 'area', 'areas', 'turkey', 'discharges', 'twentyeight', 'fly', 'worth', 'thirtyeight', 'valley', 'seaboard', 'wales', 'ireland', 'ways', 'uses', 'scotland', 'ground', 'river', 'steamboats', 'seventyfive', 'territories', 'safe', 'degrees', 'twentyfive', 'england', 'thames', 'subordinate', 'drainagebasin', 'water', 'considering', 'fertile', 'rivers', 'spread', 'reading', 'combined', 'seems', 'france', 'crookedest', 'drainagebasin:', 'supply', 'rhine', 'portugal', 'six', 'slopea', 'draws', 'exceptionally', 'mississippi', 'idaho', 'worldfour', 'atlantic', 'italy', 'spain', 'receives', 'cover', 'remarkable', 'germany', 'crow', 'delaware', 'country', 'branch', 'carries', 'proper', 'lawrence', 'journey', 'keels', 'navigable'}
```

I'm sorry if this is a bad explanation but its hard to explain for me. It's the hurdle that is preventing me from using the cosine similarity equation.

Thanks,

EDIT:

unique words only set:

```
{'remarkable', 'six', 'part', 'navigable', 'england', 'areas', 'worth', 'ways', 'longest', 'lawrence', 'journey', 'longitude', 'austria', 'rivers', 'st', 'crow', 'pacific', 'thirty-eight', 'gulf', 'ireland', 'drainage-basin', 'delaware', 'spread', 'proper', 'subordinate', 'territories', 'germany', 'cover', 'fifty-four', 'slope--a', 'fertile', 'degrees', 'wales', 'seems', 'exceptionally', 'water', 'italy', 'fly', 'missouri', 'turkey', 'atlantic', 'flats', 'hundreds', 'world--four', 'branch', 'twenty-eight', 'main', 'spain', 'receives', 'keels', 'states', 'portugal', 'draws', 'almost', 'contrary', 'seaboard', 'safe', 'mississippi', 'idaho', 'scotland', 'steamboats', 'france', 'valley', 'twenty-five', 'carries', 'wide', 'crookedest', 'area', 'reading', 'rhine', 'discharges', 'uses', 'commonplace', 'combined', 'considering', 'seventy-five', 'river', 'region', 'forty-five', 'ground', 'country', 'vast', 'thames', 'supply'}
```

My attempt:

```
for i in unique:
            kw = i
            count_word = [i for i in temp for j in i.split() if j == kw]
            count_dict = {j: i.count(j) for i in count_word for j in i.split() if j != kw}
            print(kw)
            for a, c in sorted(count_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
                print('{}: {}'.format(a, c))
            print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this we could designate `kw(keyword)` as `river` then we can use list comprehension to grab all of the items that contain this `kw`, note some sentences contain `rivers` so `kw in` will not work. From here now we can construct a dictionary using dictionary comprehension, we would use `j` representing each word in `i.split()` and `i.count(j)` to represent the count of each word in each item, we will also throw in `if j != kw` so we don't include `river` in our list.  Finally we can print using `for k, v in dicta.items()` and if we want can add sorting method to this to get our results alphabetically in order.

```
kw = 'river'
lista = [i for i in temp for j in i.split() if j == kw]
dicta = {j: i.count(j) for i in lista for j in i.split() if j != kw}

for k, v in sorted(dicta.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

> ```
> atlantic: 1
> branch: 1
> commonplace: 1
> considering: 1
> contrary: 1
> country: 1
> ...
> twenty-eight: 1
> uses: 1
> vast: 1
> water: 1
> ways: 1
> world: 1
> world--four: 1
> ```

Expanded loops:

```
lista = []
for i in temp:
    for j in i.split():
        if j == kw:
            lista.append(i)

dicta = {}
for i in lista:
    for j in i.split():
        dicta[j] = i.count(j)
```

Addtional Request:

```
Read all entire file into one variable as string

all_words = 'some string'
all_words = all_words.split()
unique = set(all_words)

for i in unique:
    kw = i
    temp = list of sentences to check against
    rest of existing code
    maybe instead of printing the final statement append the dictionaries created to a list
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you think there is a efficient way to do this for every unique word in the text. For example, I was thinking the key word could have a counter, for every loop it goes up by 1 element in the list

Comment: @gilbo184 are you talking about doing this same test for every unique word in a text?

Comment: @gilbo184 I would read the entire text into one string, split that string, then use `set(split string)` now you have a list of unique words lets call it 'unique` now I would do a loop that consumes this whole code and use `for i in unique: kw = i ...... ` and it will perform the test for every unique word

Comment: Yes, for every unique word I need to do the same thing as you just did for river. If I repeat the code above, that a lot of code haha.

Comment: So instead of the temp list Make a set with only unique words, then loop through the same way you showed above?

Comment: I would make a whole nother list im saying that is outside of this entire code, and then this code is ran `for i in unique:` but you set `kw=i` so it will perform this code for every word, make sense ?

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back  to you

Comment: @gilbo184 added in psuedo code to explain would be hard to do without the actual file myself

Comment: When you say temp = list of sentences, I get confused as temp is my list of sentences. I added the set code in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181451/discussion-between-gilbo184-and-vash-the-stampede).